# How to parse RTP H264 packet using FFMpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, rtp, live555

I am new to this forum,
i hope someone can help me with my problem.

I need to convert `RTP H264 packets` using `FFMpeg` to `BMP files`, i have achieved the following until now :

-`Reading H264 file and convert it to BMP files using FFMpeg.`

-`Receiving raw RTP H264 packets.`

I would really appreciate if someone can help me decode `RTP H264` packets using `FFMpeg`,
i have done lots of searchs over the internet, and found the following solutions:

- **libavformat using rtp_h264.c**, i could not download the library anywhere, although the file is there, but no way to use it without downloading the library, can someone please provide a download link and an example if possible?
- **live555 using H264VideoRTPSource**, after downloading the library, i did not understand how to use this code, should i instantiate the class? or inhert it? is there an example over the internet on using H264VideoRTPSource?

Is there any other way to do it **WITHOUT** reading all the standards `(RFC3984 and RFC6184)`

Thank you.

Comment: What is your target platform? If windows, you can download the ffmpeg binaries from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/